# Dataproc trying to connect to Postgres through JDBC, missing permissions

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

Thanks in advance...

1. I want to connect/write using JDBC APIs to a Postgres SQL instance running using Cloud SQL programmatically. I have used following jars:

   1. postgresql
   2. postgres-socket-factory
   3. postgres-socket-factory-1.0.11-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I am running Dataproc which will try to connect using step #1, but I get following exception:

```
2019-04-01 11:05:03.998 IST
Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:277)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at rdsConnector$.getConnection(rdsConnector.scala:33) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve information about Cloud SQL instance [projectID:us-east1:dB]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.obtainInstanceMetadata(SslSocketFactory.java:459)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.fetchInstanceSslInfo(SslSocketFactory.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstanceSslInfo(SslSocketFactory.java:313)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.createAndConfigureSocket(SslSocketFactory.java:194)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:96)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

2019-04-01 11:05:03.000 IST
User class threw exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
```

I understand this as a permission issue, but since I am using Dataproc to connect to Postgres what permission is missing? if I was running from a local laptop machine then I have to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to a json file. But what is the process in case of Dataproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC SocketFactory uses the [Application Default Credentials](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#authentication) strategy for accessing account credentials.

For Cloud Dataproc, a default service account is provided for you at `[project-number]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. You grant this account the "Cloud SQL Client" IAM role, the JDBC SocketFactory will use it to authenticate, and thus you will be able to connect to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave further notes for future visitors:

If the error you're getting is like:

```json
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

then it could be caused by issues with the scopes (Cloud API access scopes) of the VM instances. One way to fix this is adding the scope of `sql-admin` when creating the Dataproc cluster. For example:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create <your-cluster-name> \
    --region=<your-region> \
    --zone=<your-zone> \
    --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin \
    ...
```

Another way is edited that in the VM instances.

See the [`gcloud` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--scopes) for details